Does Chasis Intrusion Detection affect motherboard in anyway aside from security
Been trying to figure out if Chassis Intrusion detect will affect motherboard performance, features, etc. I'm very sure it doesn't but I wanted to be sure and nothing is confirmed yet.

why do you believe that all motherboards are the same?

are they not? Just wanted to confirm from what I've read online. Everything is just about how it enforces security and nothing mentioning to gating features or things like that.
